# how to upload photos flickr with voice recognition like qooqle

Tags: android

there is an application called qooqle developed by mit students. my company that i am intern in ask me to develop this project in android. but i am not good enough in android. at least can you give me an opinion where i should start for this project. by the way i am not going to develop the whole project. my project will include only uploading pictures to flickr with voice and tagging them with voice..
this is the project if you dont hear before:
Qooqle on Vimeo

http://vimeo.com/23240025

Comment: Hi nice :D i would be glad to help on the project. look first of all voice recognition. try simple program.

Comment: ok. i run it. now what am i suppose to do

Answer (score 1):

you can try the recognizer intent...check out the links below and see if it answers your query:
[sample code for voice recognition](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)

[voice recognizer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html)

Comment: i checked it before but i dont know how to use it in my project espacially tagging a photo

Comment: what you can do is : use the sample code above and get the speech to text coversion done. Now the problem is that you need to define a syntax that the user has to use, for example in the vlingo app (you can get this from the android market and play with it) in order to send a text message, the user needs to speak .." TEXT SAM are you free in the evening?"...so the application converts this to text and  detects the pattern of words like TEXT and the username. You can follow the same approach.What keywords the user must use to upload the pics thats  up to you and the logic you will implement

Comment: i also want to use it on twitter. i mean i want to send my twits wia voice

Comment: once you can do it for one service you can do it for any number of services...for e.g. for twitter the user just needs to say "TWEET this is my first tweet" . Google APIs will convert this to text now implement the logic in your application that recognizes the word "TWEET" and based on that calls the Twitter APIs and do the tweeting.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Is there anyway to send me sample codes. Not for all the project. if it is possible, sample codes of your example will help me so much.